# Access MTP (SD Card & Internal Card) device from command line in Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, usb, mtp, lsusb

I need to access a MTP device (Samsung Phone connected trough USB) from the command line. I have listed the connected devices using `lsusb` and this is the output:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem) post I have tried to find such path on my local file system but was unable to found it. This is the content of that folder:

```
# tree /run/user/
/run/user/
├── 1000
│   ├── dconf
│   │   └── user
│   ├── gvfs
│   ├── KeePass
│   ├── pulse
│   │   ├── native
│   │   └── pid
│   └── systemd
│       ├── notify
│       └── private
└── 988
    ├── dconf
    │   └── user
    └── systemd
        ├── notify
        └── private
```

Nothing seems to be related to the MTP device, how I can access MTP device (SD Card & Internal Card) from the command line?

Comment: if you are not using gvfs (eg a gnome desktop) you need to look at the other answers in your link referring to mtpfs.